# "typescript intellisense" in my razor views?

Tags: visual-studio, angularjs, razor, typescript, intellisense

I'm wondering if it's possible to get "typescript intellisense" in my razor views, as I have in my ts-files?

This is my app.ts file (when I type 'this.' the 'myExampleMessage' property shows up):

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

class TestController {
    constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
        this.myExampleMessage = "Hello";
    }

    myExampleMessage: string;
}
```

This is my default.cshtml file (when I type 'tController.', no intellisense show up):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
     <head>
         <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
         <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="app.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body ng-controller="TestController as tController">
         <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
         <div id="content">{{tController.myExampleMessage}}</div>
     </body> 
</html>
```

What I would like, is for Visual Studio (2013) to understand what tController is, and give me the properties defined on this class. In this case it would be the 'myExampleMessage' property.

I'm I doing something wrong, or isn't this possible?

Comment: You're right, this would be a great feature and I wonder why nobody is even thinking about it. Unfortunately, it's not even in the road map of future updates.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm I doing something wrong, or isn't this possible?

It isn't supported at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Do know when I can expect this to be supported?

Comment: 2013 was just released and didn't have this. Basically you are asking for better `angularjs` *+* `typescript` support. I haven't seen it mentioned in the public roadmap